# How to use extra parameters with image magick on android? (e.g. fuzz in colorFloodFill)

Tags: android, imagemagick, flood-fill

I don't get how to set the fuzz(y) parameter for flood fill:

> The fuzz member of image defines how much tolerance is acceptable to
>   consider two colors as the same.

This code is working, changing all pixels from red to green, but only if it is exactly red:

```
ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo();
DrawInfo drawInfo = new DrawInfo(imageInfo);
PixelPacket targetColor = PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("red");
PixelPacket greenColor = PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("green");
drawInfo.setFill(greenColor);
int method = PaintMethod.FloodfillMethod;
boolean success = magickImage.colorFloodfillImage(drawInfo, targetColor, 0, 0, method);
```

I'm using android-lib-magick, but can also switch to any other solution that works.

Basically I am trying to do what [this image magick console example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove) does:

```
convert cyclops.png -bordercolor white -border 1x1 \
-alpha set -channel RGBA -fuzz 20% \
-fill none -floodfill +0+0 white \
-shave 1x1 cyclops_flood_3.png
```

So maybe there is a way to add arbitrary parameters to the image calculation?

Comment: Now I went for using an own java method since I only need the simple flood fill algorithm with fuzzy color checking, but it would still be interesting long term to see if there is a way to pass all the parameters you can use in the console version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An own flood fill function in Java (with boolean[] visited, ..) lets you implement any color comparison algorithm! *self-high-five*

Accepted answer will be changed as soon as someone finds a better solution..